# Finding subsets being used at most k times

Tags: algorithm

Every now and then I read all those conspiracy theories about Lotto-based games being controlled and a computer browsing through the combinations chosen by the players and determining the non-used subset. It got me thinking - how would such algorithm have to work in order to determine such subsets really efficiently? Finding non-used numbers is definitely crossed out as is finding the least used because it's not necesserily providing us with a solution. Also, going deeper, how could an algorithm efficiently choose such a subset that it was used some k times by the players? Saying more formally:

> We are given a set of 50 numbers 1 to 50. In the draw 6 numbers are picked.
>
> INPUT: m subsets each consisting of 6 distinct numbers 1 to 50 each,
>   integer k (0<=k) being the maximum players having all of their 6
>   numbers correct.
>
> OUTPUT: Subsets which make not more than k players win the jackpot ('winning' means all the numbers they chose were picked in the draw).

Is there any efficient algorithm which could calculate this without using a terrabyte HDD to store all the encounters of every possible 50!/(44!*6!) in the pessimistic case? Honestly, I can't think of any.

Comment: What is the criteria for "winning"? Does all 6 numbers have to match?

Comment: Yes, by 'winning' I meant the jackpot winners. Already added in the description, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I wanted to run such a conspirancy I would first of all acquire the list of submissions by players. Then I would generate random lottery selections and see how many winners would be produced by each such selection. Then just choose the random lottery selection most attractive to me. There is little point doing anything more sophisticated, because that is probably already powerful enough to be noticed by staticians.

If you want to corrupt the lottery it would probably be easier and safer to select a few competitors you favour and have them win the lottery. In (the book) "1984" I think the state simply announced imaginary lottery winners, with the announcement in each area announcing somebody outside the area. One of the ideas in "The Beckoning Lady" by Margery Allingham is of a gang who attempt to set up a racecourse so they can rig races to allow them to disguise bribes as winnings.

Comment: Hmm.. The randomized algorithm here is really a good idea which should deal with this without too much effort. Haven't thought about it, thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

First of all, the total number of combinations (choosing 6 from 50) is not very large. It is about 16 million which can be easily handled.

For each combination keep a count of number of people who played it. While declaring a winner choose the combination that has less than k plays.

Comment: Yes, the "terrabyte thing" I mentioned is overplayed but still, the question remains - can this be effectively done without such storing all the combinations? For a range of 1 to million it wouldn't be that good.

Comment: @Straightfw Since we are looking for exact matches (all 6 numbers must match) there is not much use in putting too much thought into subsets etc. A more interesting scenario is choosing 10 numbers and if at least 8 numbers match, you win the jackpot.

Comment: OK, thank you :) And regarding the scenario you mentioned: wouldn't that boil down to the "store all the plays, find suitable" strategy as well, then?

Comment: @Straightfw Not exactly. First, the number of combinations is going to be higher (probably still manageable, but larger nevertheless). Second, since it is not exact matching, some thinking is required on how to match and how to store counts.

Comment: So extracting all possible eights from each play (10!/(2*8!)) and counting the eights seems the best option? I don't think there's anything more efficient as however we do it, we have to check all the possible eights, right?

Answer (score 1):

If the number within each subset are sorted, then you can treat your subsets as strings - sort them in lexicographical order, then it is easy to count how many players selected each subset (and which subsets were not selected at all). So the time is proportional to the number of players and not the number of numbers in the lottery.

Comment: Thank you. What do you mean by the later sorting in lexicographical order? Say we have a coupon [1, 12, 22, 24, 35, 36]. We make it a string '11222243536' - you mean we hace to sort this one once again? Or to sort the whole array? Also - ragardless of the previous question - won't the later determining if '112224' is [11, 22, 24] or [1, 12, 22, 2x] (where x is some following integer from the string) be a waste of memory? Or we should store them as '01' instead of '1' to not confuse the algorithm?

Comment: You do not need to glue the elements of {1,2,3} into a string 123. You can sort the sets as tuples. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order